# reset hidden variable after posting the form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to download the records of the output of search criteria to excel.
As the fields for search criteria are more than 20. I am submitting the form with POST method rather than GET.

On click of  "Download2excel", the hidden variable name1 is set to Yes. so i will check the condition in my code. Once the download is successful, I want to reset the variable.

Here is a sample structure of my code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <?php
        if(trim($_POST['name1']) == 'yes') {
            header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
        }else {
            ?>
    </head>
    <body onload="tempFn()">

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function tempFn(){  
                global_search.name1.value = "";
            }
            function gs_download2xl_c() {
                document.getElementById('name1').value="yes";
                document.global_search.submit();
            }
        </script>
        <form name="global_search" id="global_search" action="test_1.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" />
            <a  class="underline"  style="cursor: pointer" onclick="gs_download2xl_c();">
                Download2excel
            </a>
        </form>
            <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

As i am not executing the form after posting the form, i am not able to access the variable name1 is in it. I want to reset the variable name1.

Please suggest me a better procedure.

EDIT:-

I want to trigger the download, after submitting the form. As the records that are downloaded to excel should obey input search criteria.

Answer (score 3):

I dont exactly seem to understand your question. But I would surely suggest a few things:

- `header(...)` should appear before any output is sent to the browser. This means you must move that line before any other lines of output. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
- Try something like the following:

  ```
  <script>
  function tempFn(){
      global_search.name1.value = "";
  }
  </script>
  <body onload="tempFn()">
  </body>
  ```

**EDIT 1**: If I understand your requirement, you would want to download an excel file the contents of which depends on a query to the database or something. Correct me if I am wrong. For that you might have to have a look at how to write a data into Excel format. And just simply echo the data after setting proper headers through `header(...)`. For this you might want to google about output Excel from PHP. I googled and I got this : http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/

```
if(trim($_POST['name1']) == 'yes') {
    header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
    //echo the data here. 
}
else {
    //the form goes here
}
```

**EDIT 2**
No! every single character 'outside' the  tags are 'outputted' to the browser. In your case `<html><head>` will go to the browser. Then you set the content type within PHP script, which is incorrect.
Try this instead:

```
 <?php
    if(trim($_POST['name1']) == 'yes') {
        header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
    }else {
        ?>
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function tempFn(){  
            global_search.name1.value = "";
        }
        function gs_download2xl_c() {
            document.getElementById('name1').value="yes";
            document.global_search.submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="tempFn()">
    <form name="global_search" id="global_search" action="test_1.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" />
        <a  class="underline"  style="cursor: pointer" onclick="gs_download2xl_c();">
            Download2excel
        </a>
    </form>
        <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope I answered with an EDIT

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't get the form during the second time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, i should not get the form after posting the form. But even then name1 variable is not getting unset with onload event. I have update my code. Please check it.

Comment: Thanku. As i am submitting the same form for other purposes as well..Inorder to differentiate by what action the page has been submitted, once the download is triggered, I want to reset the variable name1. I executed the same code that you have mentioned above. It is triggering the download but the text field is not reset.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** new answer based on edited question
In order to do what you want you need to use GET variables and spawn a new window

Example

```
  if( isset($_GET['name1']) ) // if the field is set then we are receiving the form fields
  {
        //Process Fields here


        //Send file here
        header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
        $handle = fopen("filename","r");
        echo fread($handle,filesize($filename.".xls"));
        fclose($handle);
        die; //We kill the script here so it doesnt try to print the rest of the file
    }

?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function gs_download2xl_c() {
        //get fields
        var Query = new Array();
        Query.push( "name="+document.getElementById("name1") );

        url = "test_1.php?"+Query.join("&");
        window.open(url);
        document.getElementById("global_search").reset();
    }
</script>
<form name="global_search" id="global_search" action="test_1.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" />
    <a  class="underline"  style="cursor: pointer" onclick="gs_download2xl_c();">
        Download2excel
    </a>
</form>
```

Comment: yea misunderstood your question, reedited to what should work. Edit: actually still not fully understanding... Are you just trying ot trigger a download, or are you needing to submit information as well, as the name1 field has no real purpose except to trigger what looks like the start of a download

Comment: Thanku for ur attempt. But i executed the above code. First time onclick download2excel nothing is happening. second time download to excel dialog is coming. But the value of the variable is still being the same. It is not reset.